# How to nest *position: sticky* inside of mat-expansion-panel => css grid

Tags: css, angular-material, css-grid

Inside of an accordion, I have a grid with 2 columns (really more but for simplicity here) both of variable length (dynamic form creator). In the left column I have some buttons I want to stay on the screen when scrolling down the right column. Is css grid or expansion panels contradicted with sticky? I tried to find overflow being hidden as I read you couldn't do that, but I did not find that. Do you see what I'm missing and why my sticky doesn't stay?

.html

```
...
<mat-expansion-panel>
   <mat-expansion-panel-header>
        Header
   </mat-expansion-panel-header>
   <div class="grid">
        <div id="left">
           <div class=sticky>
              stay on screen
           </div>
        </div>
        <div id="right">
              some other really long content
        </div>                      
    </div>
    </mat-expansion-panel>
</mat-accordion>
...
```

.css

```
.sticky {
    position: sticky;
    top:0;
}

.grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 2fr 8fr;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

I ran into a situation where I needed the expanded `mat-expansion-panel-header` to stick to the top of the page as you scrolled.

@Mateusz Budzisz's answer talked about using `overflow: inherit !important` on the `.mat-expansion-panel`, but this would leave the page with a ton of empty space and scrollbars resulting from the overflowed (but `height: 0`'d) expansion panel body.

I solved this issue by adding this rule:

```
.mat-expansion-panel {
    overflow: inherit !important;
}

.mat-expansion-panel-body {
    overflow: hidden; // This rule fixes extra whitespace
}

.mat-expansion-panel-header.mat-expanded {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1000;
}
```

Now all expanded panel headers stick to the top of the page as they should and there is no empty space when the panels are closed.

I originally tried adding the `overflow: hidden;` rule to just the `.mat-expansion-panel-content`, but this made the expand/close animations of the panel behave weird.

Comment: I needed to add `background-color: inherit;` to the `.mat-expansion-panel-header.mat-expanded` selector to prevent multiple expanded headers from showing through when they cover each other

Answer (score 2):

`<mat-expansion-panel>` has overflow: **hidden**; You can fix position sticky by removing it, like this:

```
.mat-expansion-panel {
 overflow: inherit !important;
}
```

But it will result in empty space after panel if any panel is collapsed. More about this css issue: https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/865